# Vim how to create .swp file manually?

Tags: linux, vim, vi, swap

> [Q:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30650483/2337276) Vim creates .swp files for recovery. In case you fail to save, vim
>   will be able to recover (at least some of) the file.

How to create `.swp` files manually?

Comment: Have you checked that Vim didn't already automatically create it? It usually does, unless you only `:view` a file or explicitly `:set noswapfile`.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using generic Unix tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Vim stores the things you changed in a swap file.  Using the original
>   file you started from plus the swap file you can mostly recover your
>   work.

You don't need to create it manually. When you use vim open a file, it will be created. You can use `:sw` to see the filename. When vim close normally it will removed. The file will exists if you encounter a crash.

So if you want to create it, open the file, use `:sw`  or use `ls -a` in another tty find the `.swp` file. Then copy it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, I wanted to create a `.swo` file and this is how I did it:

- Open the file I want to have a `.swo` swap file. *This creates the `.swp` file.*
- In another terminal I opened the same file and was prompted with the `Swap file ".[file_name].swp" already exists!` message and I selected the `Edit Anyway` option. *This created the `.swo` file*

Apparently, vim will decrement the last letter every time a swap file already exists, until there is a `.saa` file.

> If the ".swp" file name already exists, the last character is
> decremented until there is no file with that name or ".saa" is
> reached.  In the last case, no swap file is created.

Source: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html